# moving vb.net solution to another machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open a solution built in VB.Net 2010 express on a second machine. Both machines are running the same version of VB.Net - the first Dev machine is running vista home premium and the new machine vista business both 32bit. I thought that everything required for a project is within the top level directory (the solution) - i usually make regular copies of an entire solution as a safety backup as i work and it works fine. But trying to open it on another machine throws all kind of Build errors.

I fixed some in the manifest: requestedExcecutionLevel I set to requireAdministrator
and turned OneClick Off.

Now it throws a new Buld error:
Assembly'My Project\app.manifest' has mismatched identity 'MyApplication.app, expected file name: 'MyApplication.app.manifest'.

Before i go rooting around changing more stuff - is this normal or an issue? its the same project no files have changed from one machine to the next, why the need to mess around in the app.config and app.manifest files??

BTW: The References Tab in Project My Project properties is not showing any references and simply displays the error:
An error occurred trying to load this page
External Component has thrown an exception

Comment: Are you relying on any third party assemblies that are registered on the other machine,perhaps?

Comment: @w00511971 - i dont think so, by that do you mean references? (i'm fairly new to .NET so excuse my ignorance) - i havent added any references since its a fairly simple App - does each physical machine require a different GUID or something??

Comment: I setup a new development PC a while ago and transferred a VB.NET project.  I had hundreds of errors.  The problem was that I was using Oracle.DataAccess API, but it was registered on the new PC with a different version.

Comment: Well Ive not added anything, im almost using vb in its default state 'out-of-the-box' no databases, general form controls, no custom classes etc when i compare manifest files they are identical. It seems to have a problem with the manifest - if i delete it and would VB re-create it again. I moved the solution to the new pc via a USB stick could that be an issue? im clutching at straws to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Instead of solution file can u open the vbproject file? Correct version of framework installed? 32/64 bit processor?

Comment: @ high wingers, Just tried that but still getting same errors. The error pops up when i hit debug/run:  "The application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Review the manifest file for possible errors. reinstalling the application may fix this problem ...."

Comment: Both laptops are running the same version of VB-Express 2010 (from the same download) Both laptops are 32Bit and bot running Vista (Home Premium and Business), Both have .Net 3.5 and 4.0 installed. Not sure what the version 4.0 variants mean(client profile, extended, multi-targeting pack) but its the same on both laptops anyway. The only way they could be any more similar is if they were both running 'Home Premuim' edition. This seems like typical MS BS

Comment: not answered - how come people tick a response which isn't a solution  - 1 tick for what exactly?? the suggestion isnt the solution, still have same problem - wish i had enough kudo on this forum to untick stuff - ill look elsewhere.

Comment: 1 tick does not mean answer has been accepted, maybe it helped someone with their issue or it made sense to someone.